# How to access argument of tuple enum inside method in Rust

Tags: enums, rust

In the following code, how can I access the string `"hello"` (which I passed when defining `m`)?

```rust
enum Message {
    Quit,
    Move { x: i32, y: i32 },
    Write(String),
    ChangeColor(i32, i32, i32),
}

impl Message {
    fn call(&self) {
        // How to access "hello" string from here?
    }
}

let m = Message::Write(String::from("hello"));
m.call();
```

Comment: Pattern match with `if let Message::Write(x) = self { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `enum Message` can be in any number of states, you have to be in correct state to extract hello.

```rust
fn call(&self) {
   match self {
      Message::Write(string) => println!("{}", string),
      _ => {},
   }
}
```

[Rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e9c14e66b7f64a9da9ff2774860bd864)

EDIT: user4815162342 solution is also right, you can use `match` or `if let` interchangeably.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use pattern matching to extract the string:

```rust
if let Message::Write(s) = self {
    assert_eq!(s, "hello");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a61aeb27cfddc9ec9abac4b10f46b171)